# R: Is it possible to print the title of a duplicate row?

Tags: r

I do a simple

```
 csv <- read.csv('omg.csv', sep=' ', row.names=1)
```

and get

duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

It would have been helpful to instantly print *which* row name was a duplicate. Is there an easy way of doing this, short of sorting the CSV file and whatnot? Surely R internally knows the names of the offending rows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file without asking that a particular column be used for row names:

```
csv <- read.csv('omg.csv', sep=' ')
```

and look for the indices of duplicates in the first column:

```
which(duplicated(csv[, 1]))
```

You can also use `table` to identify the duplicated values and their respective frequency:

```
tab <- table(csv[, 1])
tab[tab > 1]
```

---

What you want to do from here is really up to you. You could just drop the `row.names = 1` and be happy with it. But if you really want that first column to be used as row names, you will need to do something to address these duplicates. You could fix the file manually or create unique row names programmatically as follows:

```
rownames(csv) <- make.names(csv[, 1], unique = TRUE)
csv <- csv[, -1]
```